# Как отловить принудительное завершение консольного приложения? C#

Tags: c#, консоль

Существует консольное приложение. В общий лог пишется кто и когда его запускал, ну и всякие нужные входные данные.
Так вот, необходимо отловить те случаи, когда закрывают консоль, либо убивают процесс в диспетчере задач, И ВЫВЕСТИ ЭТО В ЛОГ

Comment: Отловить закрытие консоли пользователем можно с помощью подписки на ивент закрытия (Close, насколько я помню). Отловить закрытие консоли сторонним приложением можно только другим приложением. Пример: запускаете с основным приложением ещё одно и через него запускаете таску, через которую отслеживаете основное

Comment: Для логирования можете использовать NLog

Comment: Моя программа, с моим кодом, я имею доступ к коду. Код мой. В ней надо отловить закрытие, нажатие на крестик или убийство через ДЗ. Логирование есть, забудьте про него. Нужно просто что то написать в лог когда происходит "Принудительное завершение" . Остальное не важно.(Для особо одаренных, если я написал C# то можно было и понять, что приложение написано на .net и меня интересует работа с данной платформой, а конкретно с консольным приложение. Надеюсь достаточно доходчиво.)

Comment: Вам бы поучиться с людьми общаться =) Просто попросили больше деталей. Напоминаю: **это бесплатная помощь**, вам **никто** не обязан помогать. Хотите помощь - попросите нормально и общайтесь тоже нормально. Вот, возможно то, что решает Ваш вопрос. [Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1119869/17025310)

Comment: Поверь, с людьми я общаться умею. Вы же меня все-так поняли? ;) Спасибо за ответ, но к сожалению это не помогло. При закрытии консоли, та повисла и  вылетела.

Comment: @yava43DEVELOPER Я ведь дал вам ответ - создаёте ещё одно приложение, которое запускаете параллельно с основным. Через это приложение отслеживаете состояние основного. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20533/How-to-know-when-the-Task-Manager-kills-your-app Вот ссылка на пример, как это сделать. Просто вставьте эту реализацию себе или подправьте под свои нужды

Comment: Подписка на событие `EventsThreadShutdown` класса [SystemEvents](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) позволит отловить закрытие консоли. Но убийство процесса в диспетчере задач - нет. \ Событие `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit` функционирует аналогично.

Comment: _если я написал C# то можно было и понять, что приложение написано на .net_ - не факт. Ничто не запрещает написать множество компиляторов для одного языка, создающих код под разные платформы.

Comment: Создать второй процесс, который будет отслеживать закрытие первого - это распространённый способ. Вот только как на него будут реагировать антивирусы?..